# How do you deal with multiple values in a single cell separated by comma?

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, data-analysis, first-normal-form

Suppose you have a table that is setup like:

| Student | Fruits |
| --- | --- |
| Foo | Apple,Banana |
| Bar | Orange |
| Baz | Lemon,Orange |

What is your usual approach if you need to quantify/do analysis on Fruits?

One approach I've used is to create multiple helper columns, then split the values like so:

| Student | Fruits | fruit1 | fruit2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | Apple,Banana | Apple | Banana |
| Bar | Orange | Orange |  |
| Baz | Lemon,Orange | Lemon | Orange |

But I'm not sure if this is the best approach, as this leads to having both horizontally and vertically entered data. So if I need to, say find out the fruits for 'Foo' in a conventional way, I'd have to again restructure this so that each fruit is in its own row to make it "spreadsheet readable". It also doesn't translate too well if I need to create pivot tables.

Is there a better approach for this kind of task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data should preferably be normalized to the [first-normal-form](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/first-normal-form/info):

| Student | Fruits |
| --- | --- |
| Foo | Apple |
| Foo | Banana |
| Bar | Orange |
| Baz | Lemon |
| Baz | Orange |

You can try formulas like the one below to make the transformation.

```js
=QUERY(
  WRAPROWS(
   FLATTEN(
    MAP(
     A1:A4,
     B1:B4,
     LAMBDA(a,b,
      TOROW(
       REDUCE(,SPLIT(b,","),
        LAMBDA(ac,cur,
          VSTACK(ac,{a,cur}))))))),2),
 "where Col1<>''")
```

Answer (score 2):

In these cases I usually restructure the data in a more spreadsheet-friendly format, using a formula along the lines of:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   QUERY(
     SPLIT(TOCOL(A2:A4&"|"&SPLIT(B2:B4,",")),"|"),
     "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do this may not always be needed as there are cases in which it's not difficult to work with the unstructured data.